# How to test class methods in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, oop

I have a python class with methods that depend on attributes to be instantiated by other methods in the same class, such as:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
        self.d = None

    def run(self):
        self.foo()
        self.foo2()
    
    def foo(self):
        self.c = self.a * 4
    
    def foo2(self):
        self.d = self.c + self.a
```

In this example above, `foo` is always executed before `foo2`. I want to perform unit tests on this class. As I understand a unit test should test a small piece of code with independent inputs and outputs. Each `unittest` method is also independent from the next, meaning there should be no order in which each test is executed.

**However, If I want to test the quality of results of `foo` and `foo2`, how can that be tested independently?**

If `foo2` is run before `foo` then `self.c` is still `None` which results in a bad test.

1. Is there something I am missing in the `unittest` module?
2. Is there another module I should be using for tethe sting dependent methods of a class?
3. Is my understanding of `unittest` wrong? (meaning I should initialize the class and run each method in a sequence?)

Comment: Why don't you add two more keyword arguments `c=None,d=None` and change `self.c = c` and `self.d = d` in `__init__`. Then if you want just pass that `c` or `d` while you are testing a particular method

Comment: You test methods independently with mocked dependencies. So, to test `foo` and `foo2` you call them directly. To test `run` you [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) `foo` and `foo2` and check if the Mocks are called. That's all `run` does.

Comment: As far as I understand, `foo` and `foo2` should not be called from outside due to this dependency, e.g. they are "private" helper methods (this can be shown by prepending an underscore, but that is only a convention). In this case, I would only test `run`, which is the "public" interface of the class, and not the implementation details provided by the helper functions.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen but `run` is a long method does it make sense to make a unittest on it? There are a lot of things in it to test.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing it, but generally it is best to write code with testability in mind from the beginning. If it is the only public method, I would indeed test it, maybe by mocking dependencies away, or maybe I would first refactor it. If you want to have an opinion on how to best refactor existing code to be better testable, you could post your (real) code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).